# Use OnSelectIndexChanging to disable link button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using two gridview that would have the actions to select, update and delete. When the page loads the update and delete button is disabled. When the user clicks the select button the data is displayed in another gridview. The update and delete button should only be enabled when the select button for that row is clicked otherwise disable. My issue is that when select the row and then select another both rows update and delete button is enabled and it should be one row enabled.

```
 protected void Batch_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = Batch.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];


        string a = row.Cells[0].Text; //Batch ID row
        string b = row.Cells[1].Text; //UPC row
      
        LinkButton Change = row.FindControl("Change") as LinkButton;
        LinkButton Remove = row.FindControl("Remove") as LinkButton;

        if (Batch.SelectedRow != null)
        {
            Change.Enabled = true;
            Change.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark text-success border-dark";
            Remove.Enabled = true;
            Remove.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark text-danger border-dark";

            row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#F5ECAB"); //Change Row Colour on Select 

            //Bind GridView Data based on BatchID and UPC of SelectedRow
            GetBCDetailsByUpc(a, b);
        }
        else
        {
            Change.Enabled = false;
            Change.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark disabled text-success border-dark";
            Remove.Enabled = false;
            Remove.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark disabled text-danger border-dark";
        }
        
        

    }
```

Comment: As I am looking into your code, I think you're missing the part where the prior row to be disable. You're only enabling the new selected index, not the prior. In order to disable the last one you should know the current and prior in some kind of variable

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentRowIndex = -1;
protected void Batch_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow newRow = Batch.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    //Disable your current
    if(currentRowIndex > -1){
      GridViewRow currentRow= Batch.Rows[currentRowIndex];
      LinkButton currentRow_Change = currentRow.FindControl("Change") as LinkButton;
      LinkButton currentRow_Remove = currentRow.FindControl("Remove") as LinkButton;
      currentRow_Change.Enabled = false;
      currentRow_Change .CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark disabled text-success border-dark";
      currentRow_Remove.Enabled = false;
      currentRow_Remove.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark disabled text-danger border-dark";
    }
    
    string a = newRow.Cells[0].Text; //Batch ID row
    string b = newRow.Cells[1].Text; //UPC row
  
    LinkButton Change = newRow.FindControl("Change") as LinkButton;
    LinkButton Remove = newRow.FindControl("Remove") as LinkButton;

    //Enable new row selected
    Change.Enabled = true;
    Change.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark text-success border-dark";
    Remove.Enabled = true;
    Remove.CssClass = "btn btn-sm btn-dark text-danger border-dark";

    newRow.BackColor = Color.FromName("#F5ECAB"); //Change Row Colour on Select 

    //Bind GridView Data based on BatchID and UPC of SelectedRow
    GetBCDetailsByUpc(a, b);
    
    
     currentRowIndex = e.newSelectedIndex;
}
```

Comment: What should I be putting here //Disable your current
    //...? Wouldn't the link button be null

Comment: Oh, let me edit it. But it is basically what you do to disable

Comment: But if you have two same name declared  LinkButton Change and
      LinkButton Remove that gives an error. Additionally I see you using variable row still

Comment: Made some changes to your answer but it still behave the same way

Comment: My bad, I copied and past without checking. Already fixed, does it still fails?

Comment: this should row.FindControl("Change") as LinkButton; currentRow  and newRow  respectively

Comment: Yes, it still fails, once I click on the other rows it enables the buttons

Comment: if(currentRow > -1) sure that is correct?

Comment: The logic is correct, since `currentRow` is an `Int` variable. I changed it from the original I wrote down that it was a GridRow.

Comment: if(currentRow > -1) but this line is always going to be false. Why did you initiate it to -1 int currentRowIndex = -1; So I'm not sure what I'm missing

Comment: Ok, haha. Just see what you were saying, again, my bad. Check it out again

Comment: Fixed that already but it still doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228278/discussion-between-adleri-and-sue).